# Excel functions (IF / AND, etc)

Tags: excel, function

[image]

Hey guys, so I need to follow the instructions on the left side of the screen and implement them into the 'Total' column on the right. (From the 'Total sales' column)
As you can see I've put an IF statement there just to test and it's very broken as I'm unsure how to begin.

I need some sort of long IF statement that incorporates those rules.
`EG:=IF (E3 >= 3000 AND <= 4999.99, print(E3 *1.25)`, IF etc etc more rules here.

However it's very wrong and I'm sure its impossible to stack IF statements like that.

Comment: E3 >= 3000 and *what* <= 5000 ?

Answer (score 1):

The method is not to stack the conditional statements, but to nest them!

An `if` statement is built in the following format:

```
=IF(CONDITION, RESULT-IF-TRUE, RESULT-IF-FALSE)
```

If you were to put another if statement if the first case is false, you could achieve your goal.

For example:

```
=IF(SALES<3000, BONUS=0, IF(SALES>=3000 AND SALES<5000, BONUS=0.025, IF(...)))
```

Comment: With nested `IF`'s you are far better to use `IFS`, ie `=IFS(E3<3000,0,E3<5000,0.025,E3<8000,0.075,TRUE,0.1)`

Comment: And you don't need the `AND( SALES >=3000`. You know that bits true because you wouldn't be in the FALSE clause if it wern't.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Lookup task.

Since you seem to want to embed the targets and %'s in the formula, you could do if like this

```
=E3*INDEX({0;0.025;0.075;0.1},MATCH(E3,{0;3000;5000;8000},1))
```

or if you have a version of Excel that supprts `XLookup`

```
=E3*XLOOKUP(E3,{0;3000;5000;8000},{0;0.025;0.075;0.1},,-1,1)
```

<sub>More typically, you'd put the Targets and %'s in a range and lookup into that range</sub>